# Sharing among all the browsers of a user

Tags: cookies, cross-browser, local-storage

I'm building a website `www.example.com`. I want to implement an affiliate program: when a non-signed-in user enters `https://www.example.com/?af-code=affiliateA` in his browser (e.g., *Chrome*), we plan to write `affiliateA` in e.g., `localStorage` of the browser, such that we always know this user comes from `affiliateA`, no matter which url of our website he visits later.

But it seems that `localStorage` of *Chrome* is not accessible to *IE* on the same machine, and vice versa.

My question is whether there is a mechanism (e.g., `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `cookie`) to permit of sharing among all the browsers of a user.

Comment: Most trackers use user fingerprinting and server side storage to do this.  (Note that even this is considered privacy invasion that should be opt-outable if possible. eg: do-not-track header)  If it were possible to do in a manner like you are speaking of, it would probably be considered a security exploit.  For example WebRTC ip leaking was used by some trackers to fingerprint people.  eg: I don't want my browser storing data that will persist on my computer and be readable by other programs once I uninstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite difficult to proove that something doesn't exist. But if we'll take [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) for a complete list of Web APIs (which I hope it is), then you'll see there different APIs for dealing with data storage [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), ..., even a [File and Directory Entries API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API), but all of them are local for a browser.

But your task is actually not in sharing data between browsers, but to identify a user. And that can be done. But only with some probability and a lot of effort.

For that you can gather different peaces of information about user's device (like screen size, dpi, network condition, etc.), and they will be more or less the same on the same device in a different browser. Also you can use other peaces of information on the server (client IP, simultaneous sessions, when both browsers are open, action patterns, etc.). But it's not an easy task.

And to add to the complexity of it:

1. One device can be used by many users.
2. One user usually has many devices.

And in no way you can identify a user on different devices without resorting to full-blown spying techniques.

But, there are trackers out there, like *Google Analytics* and you can even fin open-source projects. So setting it up on your site can be (still probabilistic) answer to you question.

<sup>Can't recommend any - never used them.</sup>

Comment: I forgot Google Analytics, which provides affiliate tracking... Thank you...